# Highschool homework problem on matter waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, waves

An electron has kinetic energy equal to that of a photon. The wavelength of the photon is $\lambda_1$ and the de Broglie wavelength of the electron is $\lambda_2$. The ratio of $\lambda_1/\lambda_2$ is proportional to what power of $E$?

a. $E^2$

b. $\sqrt{E}$

c. $E^{-1}$

d. $1/\sqrt{E}$

Comment: Hi Ron :-) We don't answer homework questions on the main site, but if you'd like to join the [problem solving chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies) I can explain how to do it there.

Comment: oh i see... i am actually new here sir... ill delete it rn

Comment: sir i ha dont have enough reputation to talk in the chat room...btw i solved the question now sir... tysm for offering your help!

Comment: OK :-) ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Read your textbook, I'm sure the answer is in there.

Now if you had stated you don't understand what the question is asking, I would have been more than happy to have explained it to you, and from there you could have extrapolated the answer.

Do the work, don't cheat

I'll be nice though and put it in a different context to see if you can figure it out from there

The energy of a photon is equal to the kinetic energy of a proton. The energy of photon is E. Let λ1 be the de Broglie wavelength of the proton and λ2 be the wavelength of the photon.

Then, λ1/λ2 is proportional to E½

The energy photon ,λ2 = hc over E

As energy of photon = energy of proton so E= P² over 2m where p be the momentum of proton.

Now, λ1 = h over p = h over the square root 2mE

​Thus λ1 over λ2 = h over the square of 2mE over hc over E = 1 over c square 2m  * square of E

Hence λ1 over λ2 ∝ E½
​

Comment: sir I have worked it out and I do not cheat. it is just that the answer does not match. I would really happy if someone explains me just the process to do it. please i am really confused. You may call me dimwitted but please explain sir.

Comment: i have understood and i have figured out the answer.... i just misunderstood it and made a silly error... iam grateful to u though

Comment: Look at my example, I'm using voice to text, only way I can type so sorry it's a little hard, but if you follow along with pen and paper. Also, if that's the case, you should put that in your question, say what you got, then ask someone to explain. Posting a question then multiple choice looks like cheating. If you show us your work and what you got, we can help explain what happened and guide you to the correct answer.

Comment: sure thing sir i'll remember that from next time onwards :)